# How to architecture file processing in laravel

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks, listener

I have task observe folder where files are coming from SFTP. File are big and processing one file is relatively time consuming. I am looking for best approach to do it. Here are some ideas how to do it, but I am not sure what is the best way.

1. Run scheduller each 5  min to check for new files
2. For each new file trigger event that there is new file.
3. Create listener which will listen for this event and which will using queues. In the listener for new files copy new file in the processing folder and process it. When processing of new files start insert record in the DB with status processing. When processing is done change record status and copy file to processed folder.

I this solution I have 2 copy operations for each file. This is because it is possible if second scheduler executes before all files are processed than some files could overlap in 2 processing jobs.

What is the best way to do it? Should I use another approach to avoid 2 copy operations? Something like to put database check during scheduler execution to see if the file is already in the processing state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the ->withoutOverlapping(); as stated in the manual of task Scheduler [here](http://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling#preventing-task-overlaps).
Using this you will make sure that only one instance of the task run at any given time.

Comment: Good enough for slight modified approach.